# windows server - resolving TLD A entries

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have configured a windows server 2008 r2 as a DNS Server for my Windows 7 x64 Client. Resolving adresses works like a charm but with one exception:

Resolving the A Entry for the TLD io. returns a Server failed error message.

But using as an example Google DNS 8.8.8.8 as my DNS Server I get the following response: Name: io Address: 193.223.78.212

My question, is this a configuration issue or intended behavior?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I've done a little bit of lab testing, and from what I'm able to see via packet captures at the DNS server, the Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS server never attempts to contact any other servers when resolving a single-label DNS name (like `io.` or `ac.`-- both of which do have `A` records assigned in the Internet DNS system).

I'd say that you're seeing a corner-case in the Windows DNS server and single-label names. This seems likely, given the the [GlobalNames zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744.aspx) functionality to support single-label names.

You should have no trouble resolving names *within* those zones, but in every test case my DNS server returned a "server failure" response to any query for a single-label DNS name *without* sending any requests to any other DNS servers (be it configured with a "forwarder" or with root hints).